# table component not working in lwuit?

Tags: java-me, combobox, lwuit

I want to display the table after selecting the values from comboBox. It working first time selection after that it adding another two more table in UI.
Can anyone say how to fix this?

Here the code:

```
package com.onmo.classes;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.sun.lwuit.Button;
import com.sun.lwuit.ComboBox;
import com.sun.lwuit.Command;
import com.sun.lwuit.Component;
import com.sun.lwuit.Container;
import com.sun.lwuit.Form;
import com.sun.lwuit.Image;
import com.sun.lwuit.Label;
import com.sun.lwuit.TabbedPane;
import com.sun.lwuit.events.ActionEvent;
import com.sun.lwuit.events.ActionListener;
import com.sun.lwuit.events.SelectionListener;
import com.sun.lwuit.layouts.BorderLayout;
import com.sun.lwuit.layouts.BoxLayout;
import com.sun.lwuit.layouts.FlowLayout;
import com.sun.lwuit.plaf.UIManager;
import com.sun.lwuit.table.DefaultTableModel;
import com.sun.lwuit.table.Table;
import com.sun.lwuit.table.TableModel;
import com.sun.lwuit.util.Resources;

public class CompareScreen implements ActionListener, SelectionListener {

    private Command enterCmd;
    private Command backCmd;
    private Command exitCmd;
    private Form comparePage;
    private Label lblLeagues, lblTeam;
    private Button btnTeams, btnPlayers;
    private FlowLayout flowLayout;
    private ComboBox comboTeamA, comboTeamB, comboTeamC, comboTeamD, player1,
            player2;
    private Image firstTeamImage, secondTeamImage = null;
    private Container teamsContainer, teamCombo, teamImages, playersTeamTab,
            playersContainer, playersTab, playerImages;

    int count = 0;
    CompareScreen(){
        enterCmd = new Command("Select");
        backCmd = new Command("Back");
        exitCmd = new Command("Exit");
    }
    public void displayCompareScreen() {
        comparePage = new Form();
        // comparePage.getStyle().setBgColor(0xaa00ff);

        String[] teamA = { "Team A", "Villarreal", "Violent Vegans",
                "Venom XI", "Betis" };
        String[] teamB = { "Team B", "Villarreal", "Violent Vegans",
                "Venom XI", "Betis" };
        String[] playerList1 = { "Player1", "Acho, Sam", "Adams, Mike",
                "Ajirotutu, Seyi", "Abel Gomez" };
        String[] playerList2 = { "Player2", "Acho, Sam", "Adams, Mike",
                "Ajirotutu, Seyi", "Abel Gomez" };

        comparePage.addCommand(backCmd);
        comparePage.addCommandListener(this);
        lblLeagues = new Label("Premier League");
        lblTeam = new Label("Team");

        btnTeams = new Button("Teams");
        btnPlayers = new Button("Players");

        comboTeamA = new ComboBox(teamA);
        comboTeamB = new ComboBox(teamB);
        comboTeamC = new ComboBox(teamA);
        comboTeamD = new ComboBox(teamB);
        player1 = new ComboBox(playerList1);
        player2 = new ComboBox(playerList2);

        comparePage.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        comparePage
                .addComponent(BorderLayout.WEST, new Label("Premier League"));
        comparePage.addComponent(BorderLayout.EAST, new Label("Compare"));

        flowLayout = new FlowLayout();
        comparePage.setLayout(flowLayout);

        try {
            Resources r = Resources.open("/theme/javathema.res");
            UIManager.getInstance().setThemeProps(r.getTheme("javathema"));
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Couldn't load theme.");
        }

        try {
            firstTeamImage = Image.createImage("/team1.png");
            secondTeamImage = Image.createImage("/team2.png");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Label lblFirstTeam = new Label(firstTeamImage);
        lblFirstTeam.setAlignment(Component.LEFT);

        Label lblSecondTeam = new Label(secondTeamImage);
        lblSecondTeam.setAlignment(Component.RIGHT);

        Label lblFirstPlayer = new Label(firstTeamImage);
        lblFirstTeam.setAlignment(Component.LEFT);

        Label lblSecondPlayer = new Label(secondTeamImage);
        lblSecondTeam.setAlignment(Component.RIGHT);

        teamsContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        teamCombo = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        teamCombo.addComponent(comboTeamA);
        teamCombo.addComponent(comboTeamB);

        teamImages = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        teamImages.addComponent(lblFirstTeam);
        teamImages.addComponent(lblSecondTeam);

        teamsContainer.addComponent(teamCombo);
        teamsContainer.addComponent(teamImages);

        playersTeamTab = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        playersTeamTab.addComponent(comboTeamC);
        playersTeamTab.addComponent(comboTeamD);

        playersTab = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        playersTab.addComponent(player1);
        playersTab.addComponent(player2);

        playerImages = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        playerImages.addComponent(lblFirstPlayer);
        playerImages.addComponent(lblSecondPlayer);

        playersContainer = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        playersContainer.addComponent(playersTeamTab);
        playersContainer.addComponent(playersTab);
        playersContainer.addComponent(playerImages);

        TabbedPane tabbedPane = new TabbedPane(TabbedPane.TOP);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Teams", teamsContainer);
        tabbedPane.addTab("Players", playersContainer);

        // comboTeamA.addSelectionListener(this);
        comboTeamB.addSelectionListener(this);
        // comboTeamC.addSelectionListener(this);
        comboTeamD.addSelectionListener(this);

        // comboTeamA.addActionListener(this);

        comparePage.addComponent(tabbedPane);
        comparePage.show();

    }

    public void selectionChanged(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Before  :" + count);
        Table tableTeam = null, tablePlayer = null;
        if (comboTeamA.getSelectedIndex() != 0 && comboTeamB.getSelectedIndex() != 0 && comboTeamC.getSelectedIndex() == 0 && comboTeamD.getSelectedIndex() == 0) {

            TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[] { "10 ",
                    "Games Played", "10" }, new Object[][] {
                    { "7 ", "Wins", " 6" }, { "2 ", "Draws", " 1" },
                    { "1 ", "Defeats", " 1" }, { "10 ", "Goals for", " 8" }, });

            tableTeam = new Table(model);
            if (count == 1) {
                teamsContainer.addComponent(tableTeam);
                count = 0;
            }

            count = count + 1;
            System.out.println("On  :" + count);
        }

        if (comboTeamA.getSelectedIndex() == 0 && comboTeamB.getSelectedIndex() == 0 && comboTeamC.getSelectedIndex() != 0 && comboTeamD.getSelectedIndex() != 0) {

            TableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(new String[] { "10 ",
                    "Games Played", "10" }, new Object[][] {
                    { "260 ", "Minutes Played", " 280" },
                    { "240 ", "Starts", " 230" },
                    { "20 ", "Substitute", " 30" },
                    { "6 ", "Goals for", " 9" }, });

            tablePlayer = new Table(model);
            if (count == 1) {
                playersContainer.addComponent(tablePlayer);
                count = 0;
            }
            count = count + 1;
            System.out.println("On  :" + count);
        }
        /*
         * if(tableTeam != null && tablePlayer != null) {
         * teamsContainer.removeComponent(tableTeam);
         * playersContainer.removeComponent(tablePlayer); }
         */
        System.out.println("After  :" + count);
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HomePage homePageObj=HomePage.getInstance();
        homePageObj.displayHomePage();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is at this code:

```
public void selectionChanged(int arg0, int arg1) {
...
tableTeam = new Table(model);
            if (count == 1) {
                teamsContainer.addComponent(tableTeam);
                count = 0;
            }

            count = count + 1;
...
}
```

This code snippet means that you add another `Table` each time you select another value from the `ComboBox` : DON'T `RESET` "count" TO 0 !